# FindStr Usages in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

Just trying to search a particular text inside files belonging to a directory(and all its subdirectories).

```
1) findstr /f:"C:\\test.txt" "TextForSearch" > "out.txt"
```

gives me the correct answer. test.txt here contains all the files that are to be searched.It is being re-directed to out.txt.

Now, out.txt contains all the matching instances but are not delimited using spaces. How to get a list of all filename(only filenames) with a space or delimiter in the file out.txt?

```
2) findstr /D:"C:\\" "TextForSearch"
```

does not search at all. It simply hangs? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The `/M` option makes findstr print only the filename when a match is found.  It should output one match per line, so no delimiter is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findstr /S /D:"C:\\" "TextForSearch" *
```

/S recersion Searches for matching files in the current directory and all subdirectories.

*  search for all files

Comment: Thanks Ted. But, when I use /f option and redirect it to a text file, there is no delimiter. Any Ideas how doing it?

Answer (score 1):

For others,

Thanks Ted and Harry.

The solutions are

```
1) 1) findstr /m /f:"C:\\test.txt" "TextForSearch" > "out.txt"
```

for searching for a particular strings in files specified in test.txt and redirecting it to a text file named out.txt with matching files in separate lines (Demilited. Thank god.)

```
 findstr /S /D:"C:\\" "TextForSearch" *
```

checkout Ted's answer!